# Using ssmtp to send HTML e-mails with mail (sendmail)

Tags: linux, office365, sendmail, centos7, ssmtp

I configured my ssmtp as below:

**ssmtp.conf**

```
root=postmaster
mailhub=smtp.office365.com:587
Hostname=localhost
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=user@domain.com
AuthPass=mypassword
UseSTARTTLS=YES
TLS_CA_File=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

**revaliases**

```
root:user@domain.com:smtp.office365.com:587
```

**mail code is:**

```
echo "HTML formatted message goes here like <b>Bold</b><br /><i>Italic</i>" | mail -s "$(echo -e "Subject \nContent-Type: text/html")"  -r fromEmail@domain.com toemail@domain.com.
```

Before configuring ssmtp it was working fine now it is sending HTML like `<b>Bold</b>` code but I want like **Bold**  using ssmtp with mail(sendmail).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set additional `MIME-Version: 1.0` header:

```
echo "HTML formatted message goes here like <b>Bold</b><br /><i>Italic</i>" | mail -s "$(echo -e 'Subject \nContent-Type: text/html\nMime-Version: 1.0')"  -r fromEmail@domain.com toemail@domain.com
```